# Dynamic array in GP/PARI

Tags: dynamic-memory-allocation, pari, pari-gp

I need to calculate number of primes from 1 to N. For this i want to divide every next number n for primes in range 2 to sqrt(n). For this, in turn, i need to store all previously collected primes.

How can i store them effectively?

Just in case, i'm not interesting in algorithm for finding number of primes, i'm interested in how to store such kind data in general. In C++ i could use std::vector as it reallocates itself appropriately or maybe some kind of list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PARI/GP, for efficient dynamic arrays you can use `List`. It behaves like the `std::vector` in C++.
Please, see the example below:

```
xs = List()
gp> List([])

listput(xs, 1);
listput(xs, 2);

xs
gp> List([1, 2])
```

Comment: @Yola: Do you accept this answer or some extra clarification is needed?

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how it behaves from memory point of view?